# Grouping SQL by differences between rows?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm taking the min and max of several data points, but some of them have the patient going to the same locations on different days.  Is there a way to add an index or code that distinguishes them as separate groups, based on an order by statement or something similar?  I want to distinguish them as separate groups (by separating that the patient left one location, went to a new one, and then returned to the original location (treating it as a new location in terms of grouping)?

Here's the code to make a dummy data table.

```
    CREATE TABLE #StartandStop (
     [hospitalname] varchar(255),
     pt_id varchar(255),
     [Location] varchar(255),
     startdatetime datetime,
     enddatetime datetime
     ); 

     INSERT INTO #StartandStop ([hospitalname],[pt_id],[Location],[startdatetime],[enddatetime])
     VALUES ('ClevelandClinic', '1','A','01-01-2020 10:35', '01-02-2020 12:30'),
     ('ClevelandClinic', '1','B','01-02-2020 12:30', '01-03-2020 00:00'),
     ('ClevelandClinic', '1','B','01-03-2020 00:00', '01-04-2020 00:00'),
     ('ClevelandClinic', '1','B','01-04-2020 00:00', '01-04-2020 19:30'),
     ('ClevelandClinic', '1','C','01-04-2020 19:30', '01-05-2020 18:44'),
     ('ClevelandClinic', '1','B','01-05-2020 18:44', '01-05-2020 07:09'),
     ('ClevelandClinic', '1','D','01-05-2020 07:09', '01-05-2020 22:22'),
     ('ClevelandClinic', '1','D','01-05-2020 22:22', '01-06-2020 00:00'),
     ('ClevelandClinic', '1','D','01-06-2020 00:00', '01-07-2020 00:00'),
     ('ClevelandClinic', '1','D','01-07-2020 00:00', '01-08-2020 00:00'),
     ('ClevelandClinic', '1','C','01-08-2020 00:00', '01-08-2020 20:02');
```

This is the code to get results.

```
 select hospitalname,pt_id,location,min(startdatetime) as 'Start',max(enddatetime) as 'End'
  from  #StartandStop
 group by hospitalname,pt_id,location
```

These are the results I get when just taking the minimum start and maximum stop of each, without taking into account the patient's movements back and forth between units.

```
   hospitalname        pt_id    location    Start                       End
   ClevelandClinic     1         A          2020-01-01 10:35:00.000     2020-01-02 12:30:00.000
   ClevelandClinic     1         B          2020-01-02 12:30:00.000     2020-01-05 07:09:00.000
   ClevelandClinic     1         C          2020-01-04 19:30:00.000     2020-01-08 20:02:00.000
   ClevelandClinic     1         D          2020-01-05 07:09:00.000     2020-01-08 00:00:00.000
```

These are the results I'm trying to get:

```
 Hospital        Patient     Location     Start                          Stop
 ClevelandClinic    1        A            2020-01-01 10:35:00.000        2020-01-02 12:30:00.000
 ClevelandClinic    1        B            2020-01-02 12:30:00.000        2020-01-04 19:30:00.000
 ClevelandClinic    1        C            2020-01-04 19:30:00.000        2020-01-05 18:44:00.000
 ClevelandClinic    1        B            2020-01-05 18:44:00.000        2020-01-05 07:09:00.000
 ClevelandClinic    1        D            2020-01-05 07:09:00.000        2020-01-08 00:00:00.000
 ClevelandClinic    1        C            2020-01-08 00:00:00.000        2020-01-08 20:02:00.000
```

Please advise if there's a way to mark or distinguish first and second visits to the same location as different.  Thank you!

Comment: why isn't there some key to indicate to group rows as part of appointment? I don't understand how I could determine what you are asking by the data you have.

Comment: This is all I have.  They're not separate appointments, just separate locations as part of the same stay.  The only distinction I have is the movement from place to place.  I want to be able to distinguish if they were in a location, moved somewhere else and then returned to that location the second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE #StartandStop ADD color INT

DECLARE @color INT
SELECT @color = 0

UPDATE ss SET color = @color, @color = CASE WHEN s.Location <> s.LastLocation THEN @color + 1 ELSE @color END
FROM #StartandStop ss JOIN (SELECT hospitalname, pt_id, Location, LAG(location) OVER (ORDER BY hospitalname,pt_id,startdatetime,location) AS LastLocation, startdatetime, enddatetime 
    FROM #StartandStop) s ON (ss.hospitalname = s.hospitalname AND ss.pt_id = s.pt_id AND ss.location = s.location AND ss.startdatetime = s.startdatetime AND ss.enddatetime = s.enddatetime)

SELECT hospitalname AS Hospital, pt_id AS Patient, MIN(Location) AS Location, MIN(startdatetime) AS Start, MAX(enddatetime) AS Stop
FROM #StartandStop
GROUP BY hospitalname,pt_id,color
ORDER BY 1,2,4,3
```